# Scrollable div with max-width of 100% of page width

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to achieve this effect:

I have a panel that's wide (its width is dynamic based on its content)

- if the page is wider than the panel, I want it to be just displayed in the center of the page
- if the page is narrower than the panel (ex. on a phone), I want the panel (not the whole page) to be scrollable.

I know it's not an easy thing to do because nothing is fixed in this scenario, but I know it must be possible and I'm just missing something.

I'd greatly appreciate any help!

(For reference, a picture of what I want to achieve)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  gap: 24px;
}

div {
  overflow-x: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 16px 0;
  border: solid 2px green;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit?</div>
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum, perferendis esse magni sit asperiores nam quod soluta odio vel in.</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a height static. Well, I dont know other form

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  gap: 20px;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.div1 {
  background: rgb(185 28 28);
  height:45vh;
  width: 400px;
}

.div2 {
  color:white;
  font-size: 2rem;
  background: rgb(0, 0, 255);
  height: 50vh;
  width: 45vw;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class='div1'>
    1
  </div>
  <div class='div2'>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam expedita voluptatum quisquam unde optio totam, voluptas obcaecati vel mollitia veniam odit ex dicta, voluptate minima eos doloremque accusamus necessitatibus nihil.
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam expedita voluptatum quisquam unde optio totam, voluptas obcaecati vel mollitia veniam odit ex dicta, voluptate minima eos doloremque accusamus necessitatibus nihil.
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam expedita voluptatum quisquam unde optio totam, voluptas obcaecati vel mollitia veniam odit ex dicta, voluptate minima eos doloremque accusamus necessitatibus nihil.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

[View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwGeA.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).